# Create a cursor to point to an array

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

I'm trying to create a search suggestion content provider, and I need to to return its results as a cursor (for the contentprovider API of query).
The thing is, my data isnt saved in a SQLite database but in an array.
I need to create a cursor object which binds to an array, but I haven't seen any sample that does that.

Does anyone know what's the simplest way to bind a cursor to an array?